# Json-server não está salvando todos os dados ao realizar POST

Tags: postman

Tenho o seguinte database mocado:

```
{
  "clientes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "xxx",
      "cidade": "Orlândia"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nome": "yyy",
      "cidade": "Franca"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nome": "zzz",
      "cidade": "Franca"
    }
  ]
}
```

Quando eu dou o get na url no postman os dados são retornados com sucesso, porém quando eu dou um post na url: `http://localhost:5000/clientes`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu mando os seguintes dados e me retorna apenas o id, quando dou o get novamente é adicionado apenas o id.

Estou esquecendo algo?

Comment: Como tá o `content-type` do Header?

Comment: Consegui já, vou adicionar a resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolveu quando eu troquei de "form-data" para "x-www-form-urlencoded"